# How to search in mysql for a word that contains in a PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysql, contains, sql-like

I have multiple variables that contains customer names and looks like for example as below:

```
$customer =  $row["customer_name"];
```

This will contain i.e.: `test Microsoft test test test`

Now, in my database I have the column `customer` and the column contains `Microsoft Netherlands Office`

To look into the database, I have like below but it doesn't give me any results:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM specific_req WHERE customer LIKE '%$customer%'";
```

I want to search in the database table that contains any word from `$customer`.

Comment: $query is a string. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: did you get any error when you run your code?

Comment: `$query='SELECT * FROM specific_req WHERE customer LIKE "%'.$customer.'%"';` try to concatenate with concatenation operator **.** and please vardump  this query string and provide us the output, so we can check query before execution. And please provide larger fragment of your code. At the moment it is not clear if you successfully connected to the database? Do you have any other query executed against the database?

Comment: so $customer is an array or a string separating each word with space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) i.e. `MATCH AGAINST`.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM specific_req WHERE MATCH(customer) AGAINST ('$customer')";
```

To make full text work, you will have to create `FULLTEXT INDEX` on `customer` column.

```
ALTER TABLE specific_req ADD FULLTEXT KEY `idx_customer` (`customer`)
```

*Note: Sanitize `$customer` to avoid sql injection*

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can do this is to split your `$customer` variable into an array of search terms, this allows you to search each term separately in the table.

```
$customer = "test Microsoft test test test";
$customers = explode(" ", trim($customer));

$queryString = "";
$customers = array_unique($customers);
foreach($customers as $c) {
    $queryString .= "`customer` LIKE '%{$c}%' OR ";
}
$queryString = rtrim($queryString, " OR ");

$query = "SELECT * FROM specific_req WHERE {$queryString}";

echo $query;
```

This would make `$query` output

```
SELECT * FROM specific_req WHERE `customer` LIKE '%test%' OR `customer` LIKE '%Microsoft%'
```

All we are doing is using PHP's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function, breaking your variable at every space character (After using [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove beginning and ending spaces to avoid searches like `'%%'`). This gives us an array of values, which we then run through the [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, building `$queryString` to match the SQL syntax required.

**WARNING**: This solution *may* be vulnerable to SQL Injection, which could be fixed by escaping the `$c` variable inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Marios No problem!

Answer (score 0):

Build regular expression of alternative matches in PHP and run it in SQL:

```
$customer = "(" . implode('|', array_unique(explode(' ', $customer))) . ")";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM specific_req WHERE customer REGEXP '{$customer}'";
```

Comment: Suggestion: You could replace `microsoft|test` with `str_replace(" ", "|", trim($customers))`